# Importing -100 as NA

Tags: r, xlsx, openxlsx

I'm dealing with a huge Excel file (thousands of columns), and the researchers have used various ways to encodeNA, icluding -100. How would I import this? I've tried

```
library("openxlsx")
df <- read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheet = 1, colNames = TRUE, detectDates=TRUE, skipEmptyRows=TRUE, na.strings=c("NA", "N/A", "-100", "-"))
```

However, -100 still appears as, well, -100, not NA.

Comment: Maybe that is because -100 is not a string but numeric. But you could just convert the values after import on the resulting data.frame.

Comment: The way I pass it, it's a string. Files are read as string before being converted to numerical values, so this should work. I'm guessing R first tries a conversion to numeric, which would always work if the string has a valid format, and only if that fails it checks whether the string is NA. I have no other explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `openxlsx::read.xlsx`. I created a small `.xlsx` document with two columns:

[image]

Then tried reading it with `read.xlsx`. The `na.strings` argument doesn't seem to work very well. It omits the last row with two `"N/A"` values (not desired) and keeps the `"-99"` values as-is rather than replacing them with `NA` as desired:

```
library(openxlsx)
read.xlsx("test.xlsx", na.strings = c("N/A", "-99"))
#   num  char
# 1   1 hello
# 2 -99   -99
# 3   3     3

# for comparison, without na.strings
read.xlsx("test.xlsx")
#   num  char
# 1   1 hello
# 2 -99   -99
# 3   3     3
# 4 N/A   N/A
```

The `readxl` package does much better:

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("test.xlsx", na = "-99")
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#     num char 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 hello
# 2    NA NA   
# 3     3 3    
# 4    NA NA
```

This was using a freshly installed `openxlsx` version 4.1.0, and `readxl` version 1.2.0 (current version is 1.3.0).

---

The `openxlsx` github page has an open issue regarding `na.strings`. I added this example. [You can track/comment on the issue here](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/394).

Comment: It looks like the replacement is done *en masse* using a sharedStrings vector pulled out from one of the components of the Excel file. This seems to be a feature of the format: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17337073/269476

Answer (score 0):

An `.xlsx` file is a zip file with a predetermined structure containing several xml files (try to unzip it to have a look).

As pointed out in the comments, the replacement of `NA` values is done by accessing `sharedStrings.xml` within the `.xlsx` file. This is where Excel typically stores strings (to save space when strings appear multiple times in different cells). However, numerical values (even when read as `character` in R) are stored directly within the worksheets xml files, thus are not being replaced upon reading by `read.xlsx`. Moreover, other programs than Microsoft Excel may not make use of `sharedStrings` and store all values directly into the worksheets xml files. In this case, the replacement does not work either.

However, using specific numerical values as `NA` values is less of a problem because it does not mess up your column classes, as do characters within a numeric column. I would suggest using something like this to address the issue:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)

na_strings <- c("N/A", "-99")
df <- read.xlsx("my_excel_file.xlsx", na.strings = na_strings) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) {
    x[as.character(x) %in% na_strings] <- NA
    x
  })) # using mutate here instead of sapply to preserve column types
```