# Exporting to excel using xlsx library and SST

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript

Can someone explain the difference between setting SST to true and false and whether it will have any impact on the excel being created.This is our code. Setting to false vastly improves the performance but we want to be sure it does not have any adverse affect on the excel.

```
const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
            bookSST: false,
            bookType: 'xlsx',
            type: 'binary',
        });
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx > `bookSST is slower and more memory intensive, but has better compatibility with older versions of iOS Numbers`

Comment: SST is  Shared String table, you can find more explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17422415/7943457